# 4 GB RAM not detectable by BIOS and the OS

Tags: ram, bios, motherboard, boot-to-ram

I had a 4 GB RAM in the Ubuntu system, then I bought again a 4 GB RAM, but this time the new RAM is not detectable by OS as well as BIOS.

My motherboard supports 8 GB RAM 800/1067 MHz RAM

old ram -> 4 GB 1600 MHz detectable

new ram -> 4 GB 1600 MHz non detectable

`free -m` shows only 4 GB of RAM.

`lshw` command also tells that only 4 GB RAM is plugged that is the old one.

Comment: Is the new ram seen if the old ram is removed and the new ram used in its socket?  What brand RAM, what model system. May be bad RAM or incompatible.

Comment: If trying the things in the answer don't help, update your question to include the motherboard model and the exact model of old and new ram.  The motherboard manual typically has a compatibility table.

Comment: Do you RAM detected in BIOS/UEFI. Have you tried to run memtest86+ from legacy GRUB menu or some older livecd?

Comment: @N0rbert stated in Q that ram is not detected by bios, and memtest86 won't help in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If  both cards are the same then the problem is most likely going to be hardware rather than software. if the machine has another slot, try it in there. check the slot you are inserting the card in. look for dirt, dust, or debris. Make sure the card is inserted correctly,
usual reasons of failed BIOS detection are:

1. the card is bad.
2. the slot or motherboard is bad.
3. it is not inserted correctly.
4. wrong card type.

if possible, try the card in another machine.
Make sure the card is not for a MAC if it is going in a PC motherboard.
And Vice Versa.

Also, `free -h` gives an output that is a little easier to read.